# How to best plot a heavy vs light tailed distribution in R

Tags: distributions, heavy-tailed

I want to create a plot that overlays a heavy vs light tailed distribution as an example and am trying to figure out the best way to do this.

I can plot gamma distribution which is light tailed and a pareto, which is heavy but they are inherently different. As such, they are somewhat hard to compare? Any suggestions of what two distributions make a good picture?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say 'distribution' do you mean density-function or distribution-function?

Comment: I think that @whuber's answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86503/21054) could also be of help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Log-log plot is your best choice.  Here's an image of mine from [this tutorial](http://exploringpossibilityspace.blogspot.com/2013/08/tutorial-how-fat-tailed-probability.html).  Top is linear scale for both, and bottom image is log-log. Notice how the tails are indistinguishable in the linear plot but very clearly different in the log-log plot.

[image: From tutorial]

As for R, the following web page describes how to set ggplot2 to use log-log scales: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html

Answer (score 3):

I *think* you are asking for 2 different distributions that share some common 'essence', but that differ in how heavy their tails are, so that when you plot them the nature of 'heavy-tailedness' can be demonstrated. Is that correct?  If so, why not use the $t$ distribution with $1$ and $\infty$ degrees of freedom?  Here is a plot of several $t$ distributions from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution):

[image]