# Why is Gaussian Copula's Tail Dependence Zero?

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, copula, multivariate-normal-distribution

I know that the Gaussian copula has a zero tail dependence (tail independence) due to the exponential behaviour at the tail. I am just wondering if there is a rigorous proof for this?

For simplicity sake, a bivariate Gaussian copula $C(X,Y)$ would do. In particular, there are no perfect correlations between $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: What definition of tail dependence do you have?

Comment: @Glen_b Limit as q->1 P[F(X) > q | F(Y) > q], where F is the standard normal marginal CDF.

Comment: In what sense do you assume that the faster that exponential decaying normal distributions' tails are "exponential"? Where do you get that from?

Comment: @Carl I'm just assuming that might be the reason why the tail dependence is zero, since the normal PDF/CDF involves the exponential factor.

Comment: @NicTamHK Tail heaviness is usually adjudicated by survival function ratios. See, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86429/which-has-the-heavier-tail-lognormal-or-gamma/86503#86503 as an example. With respect to Cupolas, tail heaviness may be irrelevant. Why do you think it relevant?

Comment: @Carl Thanks for the link. I'm thinking it's relevant because I'm looking at the tail dependency between two random variables X and Y, both of them standard normal but not necessarily correlated. So in this case, in words, it would be something like what is the probability that X exceeds a certain threshold given that Y exceeds that as well.

Comment: Not sure. Try survival function ratio limits to check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a bivariate Gaussian copula $C(\cdot)$.

Because of the radial symmetry of a Gaussian copula we can consider just the lower tail dependence. We know that the lower tail dependence for this copula is:

$$\begin{align}
\lambda&=\lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}} \frac{\partial C(q,q)}{\partial q}\\
&=\lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}} \text{Pr}(U_{2}\leq q\,|\,U_{1}=q)+ \lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}} \text{Pr}(U_{1}\leq q\,|\,U_{2}=q)
\end{align}$$

Since a Gaussian copula is exchangeable, it follows that:

$$\lambda=2\lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}}\text{Pr}(U_{2}\leq q\,|\,U_{1}=q)$$

Now, let:

$$(X_{1},X_{2}):=\Big(\Phi^{-1}(U_{1}),\,\Phi^{-1}(U_{2})\Big)$$

This means that $(X_{1},X_{2})$ has a bivariate normal distribution with standard marginals and correlation $\rho$. Now:

$$\begin{align}
\lambda&=2\lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}}\text{Pr}(\Phi^{-1}(U_{2})\leq \Phi^{-1}(q)\,|\,\Phi^{-1}(U_{1})=\Phi^{-1}(q))\\
&=2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\text{Pr}(X_{2}\leq x\,|\, X_{1}=x)
\end{align}$$

Finally, we know that $X_{2}\,|\,X_{1}\sim N(\rho x,1-\rho^{2})$, so:

$$\lambda=2\lim_{x\to -\infty}\Phi\Bigg(x\sqrt{\frac{(1-\rho)}{(1
+\rho)}}\Bigg)=0$$

Comment: I was wondering why in the partial derivative of the Gaussian copula there are two terms in the sum: $\lambda=\lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}} \text{Pr}(U_{2}\leq q\,|\,U_{1}=q)+ \lim_{\,\,q\to 0^{+}} \text{Pr}(U_{1}\leq q\,|\,U_{2}=q)$

Comment: @AlexMe because both random variables have lower tails

Comment: Thanks @StatsPlease, I'm just confused with how can one obtain the above mentioned sum as the partial derivative of the double integral (which is the form of the Gaussian copula).

Comment: @AlexMe Might be worth raising another question related to this.

Answer (score 9):

For a non-technical, intuitive view of what the tail index is telling you, we can look at simulation and compute sample estimates of the quantity $P[F(Y) > q | F(X) > q]$ as $q$ increases.

[image: Plots of y vs x given the x values are in the upper tail, with proportion of y in the upper tail marked, for correlated Gaussian]

Here the original correlation is $0.96$, but as we get further into the upper tail of $X$ the correlation decreases, and the proportion where $F(Y) > q$ given $F(X) > q$ decreases.

Comment: I think a formal proof of this observed convergence is given in my answer.

Comment: Indeed, but often people looking at this also seek intuition about what's going on. I attempted to supply some.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexMe this is how you get the second line in @statsplease 's answer.

Apply Leibniz Integral Rule to get the derivative of C(q,q) with respect to q. You'll have to apply it twice because it is a double integral and the upper limits of integration of both integrals will be q. The result is:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the answer you have provided here. It may be better to write this out in [LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Mathematical_expressions) given the website supports it and makes your formulas much more readable.