# How is this copula relation derived?

Tags: copula

In the first answer to this question:

[Why is Gaussian Copula's Tail Dependence Zero?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245638/why-is-gaussian-copulas-tail-dependence-zero)

it says:

[image]

Where does the *second* equality come from? It doesn't seem clear to me at all.

Comment: Do you know the Chain Rule for differentiating functions of multiple variables?