# Is my data fat tailed in terms of alpha

Tags: regression, kurtosis

From Wikipedia I have the compliment of the CDF parameterized for fat-tails distributions.

$$
\Pr[X>x] \sim x^{- \alpha}\text{ as }x \to \infty,\qquad \alpha > 0.\,
$$

Here $\alpha$ is the fatness parameter. According to Taleb. $\alpha \leq 2.5$ is forecastable, but  $\alpha > 2.5$ is not.

I would like to fit $\alpha$ given my data so I can mark it as forecastable or not.

I thought I would start by trying to fit my data to a linear model.

```
set.seed(42)
df_tails <- tibble(y = 1- seq(0.01,1, 0.01),
               norm = sort(rnorm(n = 100, 0,1)), 
               cauchy = sort(rcauchy(n = 100, 0,1)))
lm(log(y) ~ norm - 1, data = df_tails)
lm(log(y) ~ cauchy - 1, data = df_tails)
```

The problem is that I end up with many `NAs` so I think I am coding something wrong.

#### Try 2

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)

df_tails_raw <- tibble(y = log(1- seq(0.01,1, 0.01)),
               norm = log(sort(rnorm(n = 100, 0,1))), 
               cauchy = log(sort(rcauchy(n = 100, 0,1))))
df_tails <- na.omit(df_tails_raw)

df_tails |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = norm, y=y), color = 'tomato', size = 2, stroke = 2, shape = 1) +
  geom_point(aes(x = cauchy, y = y), color = 'grey50', size = 2, stroke = 2, shape = 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs('Red is normal and Grey is Cauchy')

lm(y ~ norm, data = df_tails)
lm(y ~ cauchy - 1, data = df_tails)
```

[image]

My error is

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

Comment: This procedure for estimating $\alpha$ is somewhat error-prone. You may wish to read Clauset et al. [Power-law distributions in empirical data](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062).

Comment: You will find it instructive to plot your data.  Generally, you can get substantial information by plotting the empirical survival function (CCDF) on log-log axes, because its slope should be asymptotically $-\alpha.$  The point is that you don't want the central part of the data or even the left tail to screw up your analysis of the right tail, which is what you're interested in.

Comment: More specific about the coding error. Your `y` includes a zero in the range and that gives an error when you take the logarithm and pass the result to `lm`.

Comment: Where did you get the 2.5 limit from? That sounds interesting. I haven't heard of forecastable and wonder what it means. Larger $\alpha$ means less fat tails. Why would that mean less forecastable?

Comment: I got the alpha level from a review of forecasting from the International Journal of Forecasting 38 (2022) page 731

Comment: Use `y = log(1- seq(0.01,0.99, 0.01))` instead. This removes `log(0)` from your tibble. (Then adjust the number of random draws you're using.)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution#The_extreme_case:_a_power-law_distribution

Comment: @Alex does the article contain the same information as the Wikipedia page? The latter only tells about definitions of fat tails, but not about the forecastable limit at 2.5

Comment: It is not the same information, but the paper has the following logic. n=1 is not forecastable then in well behaved cases. for fat tails n going to infinity is equivalent to n=1 in the well behaved case. It does not result in an expectation (cauchy-like). If no expectation exists then it is a fools errand to forecast.

Comment: At a risk of repeating myself, **plot your tibble.**  It will be immediately evident what the problem is that raises the error and even more evident that a linear model isn't going to work at all.

Comment: @whuber I plotted the data and have no additional insights as to why a linear model would not work

Comment: It you used scatterplots, you would see that the points don't come anywhere near falling along any line.

Comment: I think most CDFs can be very well approximated with a polynomial of 6 or less

Comment: The proposed model is that $\log(y) = \alpha \log(x)$. But your plot has linear axes, not logarithmic axes.

Comment: @Alex I've now read the passage and understand it better. You paraphrased it a bit strong and also with the inequality of the bounds inversed so that made me confused. What the article tells is "a conservative heuristic is to manage variables with α ≤
2.5 as practically unpredictable". And 'predictability' relates to the standard practice of estimating the mean of a population. For heay tailed distributions, one can still make reasonable predictions that don't rely on the mean, but on quantiles/order-statistics instead (unless tails are [super-heavy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/469236))

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Thanks for expounding. You are correct, in terseness I errored on stating a stronger. For the heavy tailed distributions I would assume that an instance of an order-statistics could be a random walk process and use the last value as the best forecast.

Comment: The comment about polynomial approximations to CDFs is mistaken in two ways.  First, your applications of `lm` fit lines to the *inverse* CDF (the quantile function), which cannot possibly be remotely close to polynomial: it has vertical asymptotes at 0 and 1. Second, any polynomial approximation of a CDF of any degree is doomed to fail dramatically in the tails and, moreover, is unlikely to be monotonic.  For the third time: a scatterplot will reveal all.  Superimpose your `lm` fit on that to see just how bad it is.

Comment: Thanks for teaching me something new. Also, I would superimpose the lm fit, but I am not sure my lm fit is parameterized correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several issues with this question.

#### The error message

The simplest, is the issue about the error message which is the explicit question in the text.

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

The error says that the dependent variable in the linear model is not right and contains NA/NaN/Inf. The reason is because your $y$ variable contains a zero and when you take the logarithm of this then you get an NA value. Then, when you pass this to the `lm` function you get the error. (Because you pass log(y) nested inside the lm function this is not so clear, but the 'y' of the lm function is your 'log(y)' value and not your 'y' value)

Sidenote: to fit a powerlaw with linearisation you should use $\log(y) = a + b \cdot \log(x)$. In your code you use $\log(y) = bx$ and you miss the intercept as well as taking the logarithm of $x$.

#### The fitting of the power law

Distributions that have power law behaviour are often only having this behaviour for a limited range. In your fitting method you should only fit the part of the distribution that follows the power law.

In the log-log plot below you see that you don't have a straight line over the entire range, in addition, the points in the tail are the ones with a large scatter and error. If you plot the points along with the known underlying distribution you see that the error is not just the scatter but also the error is correlated and the entire curve can have an error.

[image: example of behaviour on log log scale]

On the plot I also have added a log-normal distribution. It shows that curves that are not really straight can appear to be straight. Just fitting a straight line does not tell that you also actually have a straight line.

The article mentioned by Sycorax on the comments, [Power-law distributions in empirical data](https://arxiv.org/abs/0706.1062), discusses this issue on more detail.

Comment: This is great! Can you edit this response to show how I can find the alpha of the normal and cauchy? You say that the parameter is only sufficient for a limited range. I am curious how Taleb and other forecasters in this area handle this nuance.

Comment: @Alex the normal distribution doesn't follow a power law. Trying to find a fit with a powerlaw would give a false result which would be found out once you try to test the goodness of fit.

Comment: Is the normal fat tailed or not?

Comment: All I want to do is classify distributions as fat tailed or not. I thought that alpha being less than 2.5 or not was straight forward. It seems I was naive. How can I classify a distribution as being fat or not.

Comment: @Alex the link given by Sycorax refers to a software package `poweRlaw`  https://aaronclauset.github.io/powerlaws/ I do not know the package, but if it is the same as the article then it will use a fitting method that is different from the least squares method (it uses the maximum likelihood estimate), it will make an estimate for the cutoff value for the range where the distribution starts to follow a power-law (for this it uses some method that optimized the deviance between the fit and the data), and it will verify the result by goodness-of-fit test which can be a KS test or a LR test.

Answer (score 3):

##### You might want to use the `tailplot` function in the `utilities` package

The standard way of examining tail behaviour of data is through a tail-plot or a Hill plot (or variations of these).  The tailplot shows the tails of a dataset against the empirical tail probability, each exhibited on a logarithmic scale.  The plot can be generated in `R` by using the [`tailplot` function](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/utilities/html/tailplot.html) in the [`utilities` package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=utilities).  This function allows you to plot the data in one or both tails using a chosen proportion of the dataset (by default the plot will show 5% of the data  in each tail) and it will compare this with a specified power-rate of decay (by default it is compared with cubic decay, which determines finiteness of the variance.

In the code below I give an example of a tailplot for a set of $n=1000$ datapoints generated from a standard normal distribution.  The plot shows that the tails of the distributin decays substantially faster than cubic decay, which is sufficient to give finite variance.  You can compare your data with an alternate rate-of-decay if you prefer.

```
#Set some mock data
set.seed(1)
DATA <- rnorm(1000)

#Show the tail plots
library(utilities)
tailplot(DATA)
```

[image]

Note that the `tailplot` function also allows you to include a Hill-plot and/or De Sousa-Michailidis plot used for estimating the rate-of-decay of the tails.  To include these plots, just set `hill.plot = TRUE` and/or `dsm.plot = TRUE`.

Comment: This is really interesting. How can I find the alpha? I would like to classify my distributions as fat or not with alphas being less than or greater than 2.5

Comment: You can use the Hill plot or DSM plot for this purpose --- have a look at [De Sousa and Michailidis (2004)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27594088) for discussion.