# Question based on the @whuber detailed answer on fat tailed term

Tags: heavy-tailed

There is one [accepted answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86503/294316), but I don't get it quite. In fact that answer raised the few additional questions I liked to share.

[image]

**1. How would you define the tails of the distribution?**

Seams that this is a **fundamental** question. In this question you used the mathematical formulation of survival function but I guess you may define the tails based on areas:
$(-inf, μ−3σ]$ and $[μ+3σ,inf)$.

My hypothesis is if some distribution has "fatter tail" that would be larger area under the PDF curve in that tail area. Is this a good definition of tails of just a simplification?

I can agree that on Wikipedia at the moment there are several [suspicious satements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution) at least regarding the fat tailed distribution evaluation based on skewness and kurtosis examination.

You confirmed: *Please note that moments, like skewness or kurtosis, are not good for characterizing tail behavior.*

**2. Why the density is not the correct object to study?**

PDF for **continuous** functions seams like the best possible function to study because it must add to 1 by definition. So far I meat some distributions like Cauchy that don't have Moment Generating function i.e. don't have moments but how can continuous distribution be without a PDF?

Isn't that if we know the CDF ( I like the term cumulative in here) we should know the PDF?

**3. CDF should be continuous, and this is the reason for the 2.**

This is more like helping me to understand the dynamics behind your answer.

**4. The terms fat-tailed and heavy-tailed are sometimes synonymous**

This is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat-tailed_distribution). Would you agree these are synonyms.

In here I think the term "long-tailed" is definitely not the synonym with the upper two. Possible confirmation would be fine.

Comment: Four questions is too many to pose at once.  The fourth is answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/168851, so I will mark that as a duplicate.  The first three are predicated on the incorrect assumption that all random variables have PDFs--they don't.  Generally, when you have focused questions concerning a particular post here, please use the commenting facility to inquire first: you have the reputation to do that.

Comment: [You got](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86429/which-has-the-heavier-tail-lognormal-or-gamma) concrete question for the distributions that have PDF and you used the assumption that "some distributions" don't have the PDF. This is how complicated answers are born. :) The question you directed me is my only satisfaction.

Comment: You have it backwards. "Some distributions don't have a PDF" is not an assumption, it's a fact.  And it's not just a mathematical nicety: many of the commonest and most useful distributions do not have PDFs. When a concept (like fat, heavy, or long tails) applies to all distributions it is often preferable to explain it in a way that does not require special assumptions like "has a PDF."

Comment: @whuber, I am balancing and measuring not to ask super evident and overly simplistic questions, at least we are working with non discrete = PDFs. What I learned so far the most common examples of continues distributions are gamma (exponentiation), normal, uniform, beta distribution as distribution of distributions. I am limited, so I searched last 30 minutes to find continuous distributions that don't have PDF in explicit form. So what you just stated is *new* to me. Can you share a link so I can read more about these continuous distributions without PDF.