# How to prove the tail behavior of the sum of random variables with one dominating?

Tags: probability, convolution

Assume I have given independent, continous random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and assume that they all have support $[-\infty, \infty]$. If $X_1$ asymptotically dominates all others, i.e.

$$f_{X_i}(\epsilon \cdot x)/f_{X_1}(x) \to 0 \quad\text{for }x \to \infty$$

for all $i \in 2,...,n$ and all fixed $\epsilon>0$, then, in my opinion, it should also hold that

$$f_{X_1+\ldots, + X_n}(x) \sim f_{X_1}(x) \quad \text{for }x\to \infty$$

But how would I generally prove that? It reminds me of something from regularly varying random variables, where if $X$ and $Y$ are regularly varying, then

$$f_{X+Y}(x)/(f_X(x)+f_Y(x))\to 1,$$

but I cannot quite figure out use the proof of the regular variation in this problem

---

Edit: After some useful remarks, I do not think that my assertion holds so let's restart;

Assume that I have two continuous, independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with unlimited support $[-\infty,\infty]$. Assume the survival function of $X$ dominates $Y$, i.e.

$$\bar F_Y(\epsilon x)/\bar F_X(x) \to 0 \text{ for }x \to \infty,$$

where $bar F_X(x)=\mathbb P(X>x)$ is the survival function for any constant $\epsilon>0$ . Does it then also hold that

$$\bar F_{X+Y}/\bar F_X(x) \to 1 \text{ for }x \to \infty$$

Comment: Re your edit: this example doesn't meet all the conditions, but consider the case where $X$ is exponentially distributed and $Y = 1$ or $Y \sim \text{Bernoulli}(0.5)$ or $Y \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$. The conclusion doesn't hold for any of these. I wonder if "$X$ has a Laplace distribution, $Y$ has a standard normal distribution" is a proper counterexample.

Comment: Update: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

By "$f_{X_1+\ldots, + X_n}(x) \sim f_{X_1}(x) \quad \text{for }x\to \infty$", do you mean that the pdf of $\sum X_i$ minus the pdf of $X_1$ converges to 0? I don't think that's always true. I'm imagining a counterexample where $f_{X_1}$ has an infinite number of increasingly narrow peaks where the pdf takes value 1, separated by troughs. Suppose that $f_{X_1}(n) = 1$ whenever $n$ is an integer. Suppose also that $X_2$ is uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$. Then adding $X_2$ has the effect of smearing out the peaks of $f_{X_1}$, so for sufficiently large $x$, $f_{X_1 + X_2}$ doesn't get close to 1, so it can't converge to $f_{X_1}$ whose limit supremum is 1.

(In this case $f_{X_1}$ isn't a regularly varying function, but the question didn't explicitly state the condition that it should be.)

**Edit:** @whuber points out that $X_2$ was supposed to have unbounded support. I believe the counterexample still holds if $X_2$ follows e.g. a standard normal distribution.

---

A counterexample for the new version of the question: suppose $X$ has a Laplace distribution with pdf $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$, and that $Y \sim N(2, 1)$. Let $Z = X + Y$.

Then for $x > 1$,

$$
P(X > x) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}
$$

The distribution of $Y$ is symmetric about 2, and for $x>1$ and any $t$, $P(X > x-1-t)+P(X>x-1+t)\ge 2P(X>x)$, so we have:

$$
\begin{align}
P(Z>x \cap Y \notin [1,3]) &= \int_1^\infty f_Y(1+t)P(X>x-1-t) + f_Y(1-t)P(X>x-1+t)dt \\
&\ge \int_1^\infty 2f_Y(1+t)P(X>x)dt \\
&=P(X>x \cap Y \notin [1,3]) \\
&=P(X>x)P(Y \notin [1,3])
\end{align}
$$

The contribution from the case $Y \in [1,3] $ is easy to bound:

$$
P(Z>x|Y\in [1,3]) \ge P(Z>x|Y=1) = P(X\ge x-1) = \frac{1}{2}e^{1-x} \\
$$

Combining these:

$$
\begin{align}
P(Z > x ) &= P(Z > x | Y \in [1,3])P(Y \in [1,3]) + P(Z>x|Y\notin [1,3)P(Y\notin [1,3]) \\
&\ge P(X > x-1)P(Y \in [1,3]) + P(X>x)P(Y\notin [1,3]) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}e^{1-x}P(Y \in[1,3]) + \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}P(Y\notin [1,3]) \\
&=P(X>x)(eP(Y\in [1,3]) + P(Y\notin[1,3]))
\end{align}
$$

This gives an asymptotic lower bound for $\bar{F}_{X+Y}/\bar F_X(x)$ that's greater than 1.

Comment: But then $X_1$ is not continous with these peaks, right? I assume that all these random variables have a density And by $f_{X_1+...+X_n}(x)\sim f_{X_1}(x)$ I meant that $f_{X_1+...+X_n}(x)/f_{X_1}(x)$ converges to a constant $c$ if $x$ goes to infinity

Comment: @Tobias2626 these would be triangular peaks rather than point masses, so $X_1$ would be continuous. So I think the counterexample still holds.

Comment: The counterexample does not seem to follow all the requirements.  In particular, the support of $X_2$ is bounded. It does suggest, however, that the definition of "$\sim$" needs to be relaxed to mean that the ratio of the two functions is eventually bounded both above and below by finite, nonzero values.

Comment: @whuber good point - I've edited, I think this still works if $X_2$ is e.g. normally distributed.

Comment: I think the spirit of your objection is a good one.  Ultimately the problem comes down to the use of a PDF instead of a survival function to analyze right tail behavior: the PDF is a poor tool for that purpose.  (I discussed this at some length in an answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/86503/919.)

Comment: @whuber; You are right - I sometimes forget what weird distributions one could construct; Thanks both of you :-) But what about the survival function? Could we say something like $\bar F_{X_1+...+X_n}\sim \bar F_{X_1}$?

Comment: I think your intuition is good, Tobias; but because you are refining your conception and framing of the problem, it would be best to edit your post so it reflects your most recent thinking and is as clear as possible, especially concerning what "$\sim$" might mean.

Comment: This paper is useful: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2959759  It focuses on exponential tails, but some of the results are more general.